# function.prototype not working properly with module.exports

Tags: javascript, class, npm, module, node-modules

I have a file that includes the current function

```js
function foo(){
  /*Some members*/
}

foo.prototype.func = function(p1){
  /*some logic*/
  return this
}

module.exports = foo
```

and in the test file

```
let x = require('First file path');

x.func(p1) /*Throws an error that it's not defined*/ 
x.prototype.func(p1)/* works normally */


/*I also tried*/

let obj = x();
```

I am trying to make an npm package and it's not practical to type the prototype every time how to solve this?

Comment: `.prototype` is a property on a constructor function. This implies the constructor is used to create a new instance. Export `new foo()` and your expectation will be met (as long as `foo()` is a valid constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foo.js should be

```
function foo() {
    /*Some members*/
}

foo.prototype.func = function (p1) {
    /*some logic*/
    console.log(p1);
}

module.exports = foo;
```

and usage file should be:

```
var foo = require('./foo');

var instance = new foo(); //<---notice here

console.log(instance.func("hello"));
```